# Is it possible to change default $HistoryLength

Tags: memory, customization, history

By default `$HistoryLength` is set to `\[Infinity]`. This is often unnecessary and can cause unecessary memory usage. I can of course set `$HistoryLength=n` in each of my notebooks but is it possible change the default `$HistoryLength`?

Comment: Edit `init.m` to include your desired setting.

Comment: Duplicate specifically of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/80978#80978) to the [pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393).